# angularfire2 phone auth with invisible recaptcha

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, recaptcha, angularfire2

i try to get phone auth with Angularfire2, Angular6 and Ionic4Alpha working.
I can signIn/signUp with it, but the console logs some errors.

This is how i use invisible recaptcha:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let vm = this;
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response) => {
        vm.loginWithPhoneNumber();
      }
    });
  }
```

With visible Recaptcha everything was working well, but now i receive this error.
How can i solve it?

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to be migrating from Google Identity Toolkit to Firebase Auth?

Comment: Do you have an empty div with this id? <div id="sign-in-button"></div>